# Why is it required to check for values upto sqrt(n), to determine divisors of a number

Tags: math, proof

I was looking for the most effecient way to determine the divisors of a number. I found an article that mentioned that instead of iterating from `1 upto n`, one can reduce the overall running time by iterating from `1 upto sqrt(n)`, and if suppose `1<=k<=sqrt(n)`, and `k` is a divisor of the number `n`, then another divisor will be `n/k`.
Is there any mathematical proof why we need to iterate only upto `sqrt(n)`?

Comment: assume `c == p * q` (compound number). Now if `p >= sqrt(c)`, what do you know of the value of `q`?

Comment: well if y = a * b, finding a (when a <= b) lead automatically to a <sqrt(q)

Comment: @EOF, i did not understand what you are trying to say. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Again, consider `c == p * q`. Also note that `c == sqrt(c) * sqrt(c)`.

Comment: @EOF, I got it!! So, if `p>sqrt(c)` and `q = sqrt(n)`, then it clearly implies that `p*q > n`, which is not what is required. Thank You!

Comment: close, but not quite. If `c = p * q` and `p >= sqrt(c)` then `q <= sqrt(c)`. If you check divisors from small to large, you will have already tried the smaller (`q` in this case) if `p > sqrt(c)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: This seems to me to be a programming question. Finding the divisors of a positive integer is a frequent and important problem in mathematics *programming*--I have dealt with it myself often. This question is about how to do it efficiently--another programming concern.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: explaining number theory doesn't strike me as on-topic hereabouts, but it takes a handful of votes to get this closed, let's see how it plays out.

Comment: @EOF, I suggest you turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a divisor `d >sqrt(n)`,  then its complimentary divisor `n/d` will be less than `n/sqrt(n)` which is equal to `sqrt(n)` so you will have already have found `n/d` by the end of your algo  and  therefore also `n/(n/d)` which is just `d`.